# Conditional probability for binary events

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

I have 2 columns of data called level 1 event and level 2 event. 
Both are columns of 1s and zeros. 
I want to find the probability of a level 2 event given that the previous event was a level 1 event. 
 `lev_1 lev_2 lev_2_&_lev_1
0    1    0      0
1    0    0      0
2    1    0      0
3    1    1      1
4    1    0      0`

I am trying to do it by adding an additional column which computes 1 if today is a level 2 event and if the previous event was level 1 event. 
Then I will calculate the final probability using Bayes Theorem. 
P(level_2_and_level_1_on_prev_event) = 1/5 = 0.2 
P(level_1) = 4/5 = 0.8 
So my answer would be 0.2/0.8 = 0.25
I wanted to know if my method of calculation of probabilities is right. 
Thank you!

Comment: For case 3, how do you know it is event 1 follows event 2, or event 2 follows event 1 based on information in data?

Comment: Hi, in the data the current state does not really matter. What I am comparing is that currently event 2 is happening and event 1 happened in the previous row.

Comment: It seems the first column is order, instead of case id. Right?

Comment: Yes it is. It is basically the dates mapped as numbers. In the original dataset, they are dates.

Comment: Do you think the computation is right?

Comment: Based on given data, my answer is 1/3.

Comment: Please could you explain how you computed it? Thanks

Comment: I do not know how to pat it in comment, so I put them in Answer, although it may not be answer.

Comment: Thanks. I think using the denominator as 4 instead of 5 makes sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
t   X1(t) X2(t+1) X1(t)*X2(t+1)
-1  Missing 0        missing
0    1      0         0
1    0      0         0
2    1      1         1
3    1      0         0
4    1      Missing   Missing  

Total 3                 1
```

Sum od X1(t) =3 because row with t = 4 needs to be excluded due to missing of X2(5).

So I got 1/3.